# PostgreSQL: chain of inserting throws "column does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function for inserting a row in the first table for every input row and inserting with linking exactly two rows in the second table with id of the first insert.

```
begin
    with participants as(
      select (first, second)
      from get_contest_participants_candidates(competition_id_input)
    ), new_contest as(
      insert into contests (competition_id)
      select competition_id_input
      from participants
      returning id
    ) 
    insert into "contestParticipants" (contest_id, contestant_id)
    values(
      (select c.id, p.first from new_contest c, participants p),
      (select c.id, p.second from new_contest c, participants p)
    );
  end;
```

function `get_contest_participants_candidates()` returns

| first | second |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

**Expected result:**

table `contests`:

| id | competition_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

table `contestParticipants`:

| id | contest_id | participant_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |

But all it returns:

```
Failed to run sql query: column "first" does not exist
```

If change `(first, second)` to `first, second`  it returns

```
Failed to run sql query: subquery must return only one column
```

What's I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try using `select first, second` instead of `select (first, second)`. Without `()`

Comment: @RaminFaracov I've tried it, but it returns "subquery must return only one column", you can see at the bottom of the question

Comment: have you run a ` SELECT * fROM get_contest_participants_candidates(competition_id_input) ` to see the result set

Comment: @nbk it returns "Failed to run sql query: subquery must return only one column" too. If run it in the separate query, it returns the valid table with "first" and "second" columns

Comment: without seeing the function? we can'r debug you query, also the rest of the missing table

Comment: @nbk added details

Comment: @ЕвгенийМатюшевский we need to see all tablea and also all functions. see if you can make a https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30 which shows the error

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect syntax in here:

```
insert into "contestParticipants" (contest_id, contestant_id)
    values(
      (select c.id, p.first from new_contest c, participants p),
      (select c.id, p.second from new_contest c, participants p)
    );
```

May be you want to write this:

```
insert into "contestParticipants" (contest_id, contestant_id)
      select c.id, p.first from new_contest c, participants p
      union all
      select c.id, p.second from new_contest c, participants p;
```